# FosUserBundle don't persist data in mongodb database

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use symfony2 and the mongoDb ODM. Today I have installed FosUserBundle.

My User class is like that :

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Document\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;


/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="auto")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

My problem is after created a User with FosUserBundle create command, only the id of user is persisted in mongodb document.

If I add the following in my User class :

```
    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $username;
```

The create command persist Id and the good username.
Of course, it's the same with all the initial fields of FOS\UserBundle\Document\User (BaseUser).

Comment: does my answer help or do you want to have the mapped-superclass running by all means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) is not working properly.

Check that your Doctrine configuration in config.yml is set to:

```
auto_mapping: true
```

To work around this another way you would need to add the complete mapping information to your User entity extending the one from the FOSUserBundle.

With Doctrine\ORM it is normally the @ORM\MappedSuperClass annotation which provides the mapping for the extending class. In FOSUserBundle's mongodb xml mapping it is this line:

```
 ...
 <mapped-superclass name="FOS\UserBundle\Document\User" collection="fos_user_user">
 ...
```

**Solution 1:**

**Try this:**

- copy the [mapping xml from FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/doctrine/User.mongodb.xml) over to your UserBundle into Resources/config/doctrine/User.mongogb.xml
- change it to fit your own Entity Class
- remove mapped-superclass node
- add the id field as Id with auto strategy

You can then ommit the @MongoDB annotations on your entity completely.

Comment: Your answer help me ! Actually, I use static mapping in my project. And so I commented the `auto_mapping: true` in the doctrine configuration. This line decommented, all works. :)

Answer (score 1):

To save somebody's time.

I also came across the issue of non-working mapping for ODM User entity and could not understand why it doesn't work. The reason was I must have extended my user entity from **`FOS\UserBundle\Document\User`** and not from *`FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`*